# Como validar existencia e insertar registros con procedimiento almacenado, en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Intento hacer un procedimiento almacenado para insertar registros en una tabla, pero validando si uno de los valores de entrada en este caso: campo matricula ya se encuentra registrado en tabla.
En caso de que no exista, mande el mensaje y si no es así, que se haga la inserción.

Lo intentaba hacer de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_inserta_Alumno` (in matricula int, in curp varchar(24),
                             in nombre varchar(70), direccion varchar(80),
                             in telefono varchar(10), in estado tinyint)

    IF NOT exists(select idalumno from alumno where matricula = matricula)
    THEN
      BEGIN
      INSERT INTO alumno (matricula,curp,nombre,direccion,telefono,estado) 
      values(190523458,'GENPG070203DGRRME02','CARLOS ANTONIO CASTRO CAMARGO','COLONIA CENTRO','4354128946',1);
      print 'ALUMNO REGISTRADO'
      END -- END BEGIN IF
    ELSE -- SI EXISTE
       BEGIN
       print 'LA MATRICULA YA SE ENCUENTRA REGISTRADA'
       END -- END BEGIN ELSE
    END IF;    
//DELIMITER ;
```

Pero no se si sea correcto el procedimiento y tengo el siguiente mensaje de error en la primer linea de print:
*Print no es válido en esta posición, esperando un identificador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: TOP 1 no es sintaxis de MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- La sintaxis que manejas en tu SP no es la adecuada, ya que [`top 1` es parte de SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- En lugar de usar `print` para imprimir los avisos, considera el uso de los [*signal statements*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)
- La forma mas simple de evaluar si un registro ya existe es que hagas un conteo de las filas donde el valor de una columna X sea igual al valor que le pasas como argumento al SP cuando lo *llamas*

Te dejo este ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_inserta_algo(
                                    IN _parametroN tipoDato,
                                    ........,
                                    IN _parametroM tipoDato
                                    )
    BEGIN
        SET @conteoExistencia = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE columna = _parametroN);
            IF @conteoExistencia > 0 THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'El registro ya existe';
            ELSE 
                INSERT INTO tabla(columna1, columna2, columna3)
                VALUES ('valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3');  
            END IF;
    END;
//
```